# Duplicate closed lid behaviour having the laptop lid open?

Tags: display, suspend, laptop, lid

How to duplicate the closed lid behaviour while having the laptop lid open?
Wish to have display off on demand when running certain apps, with a remote screen.

$ xrandr --output  --off
This command keeps display off but does not send proper image to remote screen, so it is not usable.

$ xset dpms force off
This behaviour breaks as soon as you do anything remotely on the laptop, having laptop display turn on.

Any other ideas? Thx!